# Control del teclado con jquery para controlar numeros?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    if (event.shiftKey) 
        event.preventDefault();
}

if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9) {
}
else {
    if (event.keyCode < 95) {
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    else {
        if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente código para sólo aceptar por teclado números, pero necesito que se acepte la tecla tab.

Leí en la siguiente página que el número equivale al 9 pero no me sirve

https://salinasjavi.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/codigos-javascript-del-teclado-keycodes/

Comment: También deberías de compartirnos el html. Para capturar ese evento, a q tipo de inputs se lo haces? Y cuál de las 3 formas de evento de teclado usas?

Answer (score 4):

Según la MDN, la propiedad `keyCode` está **deprecated**; devuelve un valor numérico **dependiente** del sistema y de la implementación. No tienes garantías de que el código sea el mismo en todos los navegadores ni en todos los equipos.

En su lugar, recomiendan usar la propiedad `key` (un String):

- Si la tecla es *imprimible*, `key` contiene el caracter Unicode.
- Si la tecla es de *control*, `key` contiene un *nombre* para esa tecla.
  En concreto, el tabulador es `'Tab'`.

**Referencias**

[MDN - KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

[MDN - KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[MDN - Valores especiales de KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)

Comment: Vientos esta respuesta es buena :D y mucha información

Comment: La Mozilla Developer Network deberia ser de lectura **obligada** para cualquiera que quiera tomarse Javascript en serio. Su explicación del modelo de eventos https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop es lo mejor que he visto al respecto en cualquier parte. La de problemas y errores que se habrían ahorrado muchos si la hubieran leido ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Tengo un planteamiento que creo que puede serte útil. Me parece que tu código no está funcionando bien porque la tecla Tab tiene por default, una funcionalidad y es la de "rotar" por los diferentes elementos, por lo que si normalmente presionas esa tecla estando en un `input`, no va a servirte. Una forma de solucionar esto es, en tu función para manejar ese evento, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Eso desactiva el evento predefinido para esa o cualquier otra tecla y así vas a poder manejar bien lo que haces. Espero te sirva.